# about android invalidation?

Tags: android, invalidation, ondraw

Now, I have a Framelayout, it includes two views. when I call the top view's invalidate() method, I found the another view's onDraw() also be called. I suppose the another view's onDraw() should not be called, Is there a way to stop the onDraw be called?

Is there someone tell the reason why onDraw() be called?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `willNotDraw="true"` [(see here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29) to your view, but I'm not sure it helps.

Comment: it can not work. anyway, thanks. Now, I have to improve the performance of the onDraw() in another view.